# Moodle email confirmation

Tags: moodle

When a new user register, moodle send confirmation email to user, from the language file lang/en/moodle.php with a string "emailconfirmation" by a moodle function:

```
function send_confirmation_email($user) {
global $CFG;

$site = get_site();
$supportuser = generate_email_supportuser();

$data = new stdClass();
$data->firstname = fullname($user);
$data->sitename = format_string($site->fullname);
$data->admin = generate_email_signoff();

$subject = get_string('emailconfirmationsubject', '', format_string($site->fullname));

$username = urlencode($user->username);
$username = str_replace('.', '%2E', $username); // prevent problems with trailing dots
$data->link = $CFG->wwwroot .'/login/confirm.php?data='. $user->secret .'/'. $username;
$message = get_string('emailconfirmation', '', $data);
$messagehtml = text_to_html(get_string('emailconfirmation', '', $data), false, false, true);

return email_to_user($user, $subject, $message, $messagehtml);
}
```

Moodle redirects to index.php after confirmation. How do I redirect $data->link to a custom page after confirmation:

```
if (send_confirmation_email($user)) {
    if (AUTH_CONFIRM_OK = true) {
       $urltogo = new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . "/coursestat/view.php", array('id' => $statid));
       redirect($urltogo);
    }
 }
 else
   print_error('auth_noemail','auth_email');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use $data->link assuming its a string?

```
if (send_confirmation_email($user)) {
    // Assuming $data->link is a string?
    $urltogo = new moodle_url($data->link);
    redirect($urltogo);
}
```

This line

```
if (AUTH_CONFIRM_OK = true) {
```

Doesn't make sense, `AUTH_CONFIRM_OK` is a constant. Also `=` is an assignment. I'm guessing you meant something like this:

```
if ($somevariable == AUTH_CONFIRM_OK) {
```